# Bash-скрипт на подключение по ssh к нескольким сотням машин

Tags: bash, centos, ssh, автоматизация, expect

Дано: около трёх сотен машин в закрытой сети под управлением CentOS (22 порт открыт, вход по паролю, доступ к репам отсутствует, либо они закрыты).

Требуется, чтобы запускался bash-скрипт на отдельной машине (в этой сети), который бы делал следующее:

1. Ломился на все эти машины по ssh по логину/паролю.
2. Изменял файлик реп.
3. Ставил нужный пакет и отключался.

Либо так (даже предпочтительнее):

1. Ломился на все эти машины по ssh по логину/паролю.
2. Качал wget'ом с заранее известного адреса нужный пакет.
3. Ставил его и отключался.

P.S. С написанием скриптов автоматизации знаком поверхностно, готов выслушать критику и жду предложений, по какому пути идти.

**UPDATE:**

*Костыльное решение, конечно. Но вдруг кому пригодится. Особенно, если нет возможности удалённо поставить ansible или puppet, но позарез нужно подключиться к серверу именно без ключей.*

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

log_file expect.log
exp_internal 0
set timeout 300
set USER "пользователь"
set PASS "пароль"
set HOST "ip-адрес"

spawn ssh -p 22 -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $USER@$HOST
expect "*assword" {send "$PASS\r"}
expect "#" {send "cd /home/\r"}

send "wget -P /home http://ПУТЬ/ИМЯ_ПАКЕТА.rpm\r"
send "yum --nogpgcheck localinstall -y ИМЯ_ПАКЕТА.rpm\r"

expect "#" {send "rm *.rpm -f\r"}
expect "#" {send "exit\r"} 
expect eof
```

Comment: скрипты не должны ходить по логину и паролю. для этого в ssh придуманы ключи https://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh.ru.html

Comment: И если задача установить пакет на уделенной машине, то не ясно зачем нужен expect. если пакет ставится одной командой. Если что то более сложное, то вопрос в том на что такое может отреагировать expect чего нельзя сделать обычным bash сценарием

Comment: И есть вероятность, что стоит использовать Docker или подобные средства для поддержки определенного состояния развернутого проекта на многих машинах

Comment: С ключами вариант отпадает сразу. Скрипт нужно использовать единоразово и потом про него забыть и не вспоминать. Цель скрипта - поставить нужный пакет на требуемые сотни машин не покидая своего рабочего места (машины территориально разбросаны по всей стране и возможность физического доступа к ним отсутствует).
Docker тут вообще не требуется.

Comment: но тогда вам нужен expect только на машине с которой отдаете команды

Comment: даже так? очень круто. это намного облегчает задачу

Comment: вам же надо только заметить что ssh спросил и передать его. после этого передавать команды. ну над анализом ответов этих команд надо будет конечно думать. Ну или просто сваливать в лог все неожиданные ответы и прерывать выполнение команд на этой машине

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: Может стоит для такой задачи использовать чё-нить типа `ansible`?

Comment: конкретно для этой задачи, к сожалению, невозможно применить ansible. данное костыльное решение направлено на разовую массовую установку необходимого пакета. в дальнейшем планируется использовать такие инструменты, как puppet и, возможно, ansible